# How can I import subtitles/captions into a letterboxed video like this?

Tags: premiere, ffmpeg, subtitles, closed-captioning

How can I easily create captions that look like this?

[image]
[(Click to see a video that shows a good example.)](https://www.facebook.com/CoachMatthewHussey/videos/1373545812664485/)

I have a video that is 1280 x 720 pixels but converted to a square of 1280 x 1280 pixels so that there is empty space above and below.

Using Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2017, I've then added a "Default Still" Title to the top.

**Given an `.srt` or other file of captions, how could I import them to be shown in the bottom band of the video at the appropriate time?**

I want them "burned in" so that they are always visible regardless of the device used to play the video.

(So maybe they're called "open captions" instead of "closed captions".)

I want to be able to choose the font style and size.

I want to avoid creating a "Default Still Title" for each sentence of text manually—that would be a lot of hassle for a long video.

I have Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2017 but could buy other software if necessary or could use `ffmpeg` if that is capable.

Comment: Can be easily done with ffmpeg. But Premiere, IIRC, can do it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ffmpeg`. Make your subtitles with [Aegisub](http://www.aegisub.org/) or manually with a text editor. [ASS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubStation_Alpha#Advanced_SubStation_Alpha) subtitles are fancier, but [SRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip) are simpler if you want to manually make them.

## Alignment & Margin

The default settings will likely work, but you can control the general location, or *alignment*, using the "keypad" coordinates. For example, `2` is bottom center. For more granular control you use the vertical *margin*. In Aegisub these options are available in *Subtitles* > *Style Manager* > *Edit*.

[image]

You can also choose the font and font size in this screen.

## `ffmpeg` examples

Now run `ffmpeg` with the [subtitles filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) to make your hardsubs:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "subtitles=subs.ass" output
```

Or if you want to avoid using Aegisub you can use the `force_style` option:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "subtitles=subs.ass:force_style='Fontname=Arial,Fontsize=20,Alignment=2,MarginV=10'" output
```

Resulting in:

[image]

If you do want to use `ffmpeg` make sure to output from Premiere using a lossless format, such as [UT video](http://umezawa.dyndns.info/archive/utvideo/?C=M;O=D), because `ffmpeg` will re-encode it which is required when filtering.

Comment: Very cool. Thanks! And I'd never heard of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ut_Video_Codec_Suite Interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @Ryan It's a decent format and works well as an intermediate file. It's main advantage on Windows is the ease of installation and easy integration into Premiere.